# NodeJS Express File Upload Bug

Tags: node.js, file, express, upload

I am uploading a one megabyte file that is just 1mb of ones. It appears that any post page that does not handle file uploads will cause the server to save a temporary instance of that file that has an unknown time of existance. This is an issue that can be experienced in any post request. How can I fix this so that no one could use this as a vector of attack?

POST page http://cryptsy.tv/speedtest

```
speedtest: function(req,res){
    res.end("Done");
}
```

https://github.com/justin7674/PeerJS-SwarmConnection/tree/master/Server

Comment: https://cryptsy.tv/assets/example.png for the time being as an example of the server

Answer (score 0):

When using express-fileupload, any file upload to any post page (regardless of whether or not the post page is intended to handle file uploads) the temporary file will upload without permissions and the created file will stay in the server directory with no expiry time known/provided. This could allow for a server to be overfilled and memory maxed by simply sending a file to any post page available. I fixed it by passing this to every page utilizing POST or PUT.

```
,handlefiles: function(req,res,next){
    const files = req.files || {};
    function cleanupFiles () {
        res.removeListener('finish', cleanupFiles);
        res.removeListener('close', cleanupFiles);
        const files = req.files || {};
        for(var fn in files){
             fs.unlinkSync(files[fn].path);
        }
    }
    res.on('finish', cleanupFiles);
    res.on('close', cleanupFiles);
    next();
},
```

Comment: Have you thought about enabling express-fileupload only on routes where you process files.